# Issue with classloader

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am trying to move legacy application (ear application) from Websphere to liberty.

However on startup I am getting lot of "ClassNotFound" errors like

```
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.abc.utilities.BaseServletFil
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:397)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:375)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:285)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:943)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:888)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:535)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:495)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:127)
        at 
    com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.findClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:138)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:943)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:888)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:588)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.abc.utilities.BaseServletFil
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:557)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:288)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:943)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:888)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:495)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
    ... 37 more
```

BaseServletFil is defined in abc.jar which is not bundled inside the ear

To resolve the error, I added following configuration to server.xml

```
<application id="ABC_EJBEAR" location="abcuiejb.ear" name="ABC_EJBEAR">
<classloader>
<privateLibrary>
<fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/myLibrary" includes="*.jar" scanInterval="5s" />
</privateLibrary>
</classloader>
</application>
```

myLibrary directory is created at wlp\usr\servers\server1\myLibrary and contains abc.jar.

Any pointers in resolving this error will be helpful. Also how to troubleshoot classloading issues (for third party jars like apache commons)

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?  I'd like to see which classes are attempting to load the BaseServletFil. You can find some diagnostics with a server dump (`wlp/bin/server dump <serverName>`) - then look for ClassLoadingService.txt in the introspections directory of the resulting zip file.

Comment: updated the post